# Replace Workflow InfoPath with ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, asp.net

In SharePoint 2010, when using Workflows with Tasks; SharePoint gives you some InfoPath forms to use for Approval, etc.

**Can I replace these forms with a non InfoPath WebForm/WebPart, whatever... just as long as its not InfoPath.**

The reason: we have a client who wants httpOnlyCookies set to true and when we do, all InfoPath WebForms come back with a response of: "The form cannot be displayed in the browser because the use of session cookies has been disabled in the current browser settings. In order to load the form, session cookies must be allowed."

We've tried everything, including opening a ticket with Microsoft. Microsoft's response: "session cookies are required in order to view forms in the browser."

Comment: well, Microsoft says you likely can't; here is a response from an email to them on a ticket I had opened: "It appears that SharePoint 2007 allows you to user an .aspx for for approval instead of an InfoPath form.  It’s only possible on SharePoint 2010 if it has been upgraded from SharePoint 2007 and you have NOT installed InfoPath Forms Services on the SharePoint 2010 server.

Since you have a SharePoint 2010 server, the answer is likely that you cannot substitute something for the InfoPath form."

Comment: Plz add your comment as answer b/c ppl looking for answers skip this as not having no answer

Answer (score 1):

well, Microsoft says you likely can't; here is a response from an email to them on a ticket I had opened: "It appears that SharePoint 2007 allows you to user an .aspx for for approval instead of an InfoPath form. It’s only possible on SharePoint 2010 if it has been upgraded from SharePoint 2007 and you have NOT installed InfoPath Forms Services on the SharePoint 2010 server. Since you have a SharePoint 2010 server, the answer is likely that you cannot substitute something for the InfoPath form."